# To Make Db column Case Sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, case-sensitive

I have a database column of string type which is a primary key and case insensitive, I want to make the column as case sensitive such that it can have 2 entries like abc and ABC. I am trying like this

```
ALTER TABLE A 
ALTER COLUMN B VARCHAR(10) 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

and I am getting following error

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'PK_A' is dependent on column  B'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN B failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Comment: Do you use it as foreign key in other tables? If so, you have to change column there as well.

Comment: Drop foreign keys, change columns and then create key again.

Comment: Do you have data in this columns ?

Comment: @Rajat : It won't cost you to be polite :)

Comment: Hey! sorry..I didn't mean it! :)